# html report is not getting generated with --reporter option

Tags: automation, automated-tests, report, e2e-testing, testcafe

Here is the weird behavior and need help to understand why is it behaving like this.

I have testcafe installed using -g and also --save-dev(meaning globally and locally).

I have package.json with scripts like

"scripts": {
    "test": "testcafe chrome:headless"
}

Now, when I run the command
**npm test tests/samplefile.js --reporter html:reports/report.html** 
the report does not get generated, but

If I run the command, it works
**Testcafe chrome:headless tests/samplefile.js --reporter html:reports/report.html** 
Report is generated. In this case, it is using package installed globally.

This command also works
**npx testcafe tests/samplefile.js --reporter html:reports/report.html**

So, my question is, why is npm test command is not generating an HTML report? Am I doing anything wrong? Btw, tests are passing in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe requires 2 arguments: 'browser list' and 'file-or-glob' that specifies  the files or directories (separated by a space) from which to run the tests.

So, the command

```js
testcafe chrome:headless tests/samplefile.js --reporter html:reports/report.html
```

is correct.

The command

```js
npm test tests/samplefile.js --reporter html:reports/report.html
```

is incorrect because 'npm' doesn't allow you to pass arguments to the executing command using this way.